# Average Monthly Balance of Accounts

Tags: average, teradata

I have table containing daily balances of all accounts of different branches with following fields. 
Branch_Code, Account_Num, Date, Day_End_Balance
The table contains data from 01-01-2015 to 31-12-2015 on daily basis for each accounts. I want to get average monthly balance from January to December for each account of Branch_Code "123".

What should be the SQL Query for teradata.

Regards

KAM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select AVG(balance) from table where branch_code="123" group by Account_Num

I guess.. this should work.. :)

Comment: This will give one average balance for entire year sir. I want average balance on monthly basis.

Comment: Can we group the date on month wise basis?

Comment: Ohh..If it is of datetime type then you can simply use group by Account_Num,Month(date)

Comment: Thanks Vatsal, With little modification your suggested code worked fine. Thanks.

Comment: You're welcome... just upvote and choose the most useful answer... :)